# RXJS: Non sequential behavior of concatenated observables created from promises

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say I've got this TS code:

```
import { concat, from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const promise = (i: number) =>
  new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
    const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`promise ${i}`);
      resolve(i);
    }, delay);
  });

const observable = (i: number) => {
  return from(promise(i)).pipe(mergeMap((j) => of(j)));
};

const obs = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  obs.push(observable(i));
}

concat(...obs).subscribe({
  next: (l) => console.log(`result ${l}`),
  complete: () => console.log('done'),
});
```

I expected the result when ran to be something like:

```
promise 0
result 0
promise 1
result 1
promise 2
result 2
promise 3
result 3
...
done
```

But I actually got some typical async behavior like:

```
promise 2
promise 4
promise 0
result 0
promise 3
promise 5
promise 1
result 1
result 2
...
done
```

Which leads me to think that all of the underlying promises are running at once beforehand and then the corresponding results are merged sequentially. Is there a way to prevent this behavior and get the expected result?

Edit: what I really need is that each promise starts only when the previous observer has completed, and not that all the promises start at once.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises start immediately, unlike observables, so the issue is that your `observable` function calls `promise` which already starts it. You can solve this by deferring it:

```
defer(() => from(promise(i))).pipe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for what you are trying to accomplish?
import { mergeMap,delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
return from(promise(i)).pipe(delay(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)),mergeMap((j) => of(j)));
Use in place of the timeout.
ok, sorry I misunderstood.
This does something similar...

This example below will call each promise only after the first one completes and resolves.   I think concat may Be executing each promise all before it gets to the concatMap() in my example above .
from([0,1,2,3,4]).pipe( concatMap( i=>from(promise(i)))) .subscribe({
next: (l) => console.log(`result ${l}`),
complete: () => console.log('done'),
});

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, it would most likely work but what I really need is that each promise starts after the previous observer has completed and not that all promises start at once.